# How to compare data in Perl if you don't know if it's a string or number or an object?

Tags: perl, equality

I'm writing a Linked List in Perl. The linked list has nodes that are linked together. Each node has a value. This value can be anything, an object, a string, a number, a reference, and more.

The question that I've is how do I compare the value for equality. When writing the find function, I need to find the given value in the linked list. However, since the value can be anything, I don't know how to implement the comparison operation.

Here's the relevant code fragment that I've so far for the find operation:

```
sub find {
    my $val = shift; # we're looking for this value

    my $node = $LinkedList->{head}; # we start looking at the beginning of LL

    while (defined $node) {
        # this is the relevant part, how do I compare $val to $node->{val}
        if ($node->{val} == $val) {
            return $node;
        }
        if ($node->{val} eq $val) {
            return $node;
        }

        $node = $node->{next};
    }
}
```

Would using two checks with `==` and `eq` be enough? (Would this handle references, objects, and so on?)

Comment: What's your definition of equality?

Comment: Well the linked list is a generic data structure. So if I add numbers to it, then equality should return true if numbers are equal. If I add strings, then it should return true if strings are equal, and so on.

Comment: Three can be stored using three numerical formats and two string formats. Should three stored as a signed integer and three stored as a UTF8=0 string be considered equal? What about three stored as an object that overloads numification? Your definition is highly incomplete. What's your definition of equality?

Comment: In that case I don't know. :(

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could help me figure this out. What would be a good equality in a linked list?

Comment: Probably, three stored as a string, and three stored as a number would be different. And three stored as an object would only be equal to another three stored as an object.

Comment: Got it - in that case 3 stored as a number would only be equal to another 3 stored as a number. "3" stored as a string would only be equal to another "3" stored as a number. And 3 stored as an object would only be equal to another 3 as an object.

Comment: Re "I'd appreciate if you could help me figure this out.", Your values apparently have types. You should store the type with the value. e.g. `while (my $x = <>) { chomp($x); print $x + 5, "\n"; }`  In your mind, `$x` is probably number after the `chomp`, but Perl has no way of knowing you think that unless you tell it.

Comment: Could you also explain about how three can be stored using three different numerical formats? Very curious. I can only think of one way  - `my $three = 3`.

Comment: signed integer (IV), unsigned integer (UV), floating point (NV)

Comment: Wow. Does this mean that this is a pretty complicated problem and I can't just write a generic Linked List easily without passing in types?

Comment: Another idea that I just had is passing in a comparison function? What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: Re "Does this mean [...] I can't write a generic Linked List easily without passing in types?" Of course you can. Your question has nothing to do with linked lists. You asked how to check is two values have the same type, and if they do are they equal using a suitable comparison function for that type.

Comment: Re "Another idea that I just had is passing in a comparison function?" Passing to what?

Comment: @ikegami I imagine it would be passed to the constructor of their LinkedList package.

Comment: yes, passing to the constructor of the LinkedList package.

Comment: @ikegami So if I can write a generic LL without passing in types, could you then explain how to internally compare the values for equality? Because different data would have different equalities. Now we again probably return to the question of what is my definition of equality... Let me put it this way. If I have a LinkedList object and I `add` a `value` to it, then calling `find` with this `value` would locate it in the linked list and return it back. `Find` internally has to compare values in the linked list to the `value`, and this is the equality that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, That wouldn't be appropriate. Linked list don't need to compare anything.

Comment: @ikegami It does have a `find` operation though that would need to compare each value to find the element in the linked list. The problem I'm having is how to implement a generic compare inside the `find` operation, because there is `eq` and `==`. So should I just implement both of them like in my original question?

Comment: @bodacydo, Re "It does have a find operation", `find` does comparions. `find` should take a comparison function if it's a generic linked list. If it's not generic, then you can hardcode it into `find` if you want.

Comment: Re" So should I just implement both of them like in my original question?" No, you said three as a string shouldn't be equal to three as a number, but your code has them been equal. (Your code even considers `"abc"` to be equal to `0`.) You can't just use a combination of `eq` and `==` if you want to check the internals of the scalar. You'll need C code or the "B" modules.

Comment: But I don't think that's a good idea. As I already mentioned, you'd probably consider `$num` to be a number in `while (<>) { chomp; my $num = $_; print $num + 5, "\n"; }`, but it's stored as a string. Looking at the internals won't get useful information about the type of the value.

Comment: The type of values is normally implied from how you use the data. Pass a value to `==` or `+`? It must be a number. Pass one to `eq` or `.`? It must be a string. No such implication is made from placing the value in the linked list. If your values have type information that you want to compare, you'll have to explicitly store that information along with your values. Perl can't read your mind.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking the wrong question. You don't need a generic compare function; you simply need the ability to provide a task-specific compare function.

If you have meaningful differences in the type of data in the linked list, you must be able to differentiate them somehow or else you wouldn't be able to use the information in the list. Exactly how you differentiate them isn't important; what's important is that you must already know how to do so.

Simply code that knowledge you already have into a compare function you pass to `find` or to the constructor.

```
sub find {
   my ($self, $is_equal, $arg) = @_;

   my $ap = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::a'} };  local *$ap;
   my $bp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{caller().'::b'} };  local *$bp;

   *$ap = \$arg;

   for (my $node = $self->{head}; $node; $node = $node->{next}) {
      *$bp = \( $head->{val} );
      return $node if $is_equal->();
   }

   return undef;
}
```

Example usage:

```
sub is_same_flight {
   # Returns true if $a and $b represent the same flight.
   ...
}

$flights->find(\&is_same_flight, $flight);
```

or

```
my $is_same_flight = sub {
   # Returns true if $a and $b represent the same flight.
   ...
};

$flights->find($is_same_flight, $flight);
```

Comment: Very nice trick of getting `$a` and `$b` to work in the callback. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I guess there is a significant performance boost using aliased $a and $b rather than just passing them as arguments? I know this is how sort works, but I always thought it was a little crufty. Particularly as you need to ensure they are not declared as lexicals.

Comment: @harmic, Don't know. It's much cleaner looking than using `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`, at least. You already need to avoid declaring them as lexicals, so no new penalty. Not that it has EVER been a problem.